# Automatic mapping URL to View Spring MVC without controller or mapping registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project build on top of [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), using starters: `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` and `spring-boot-starter-security`. As such, the web and the thymeleaf starters use [web](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java) and [thymeleaf](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) autoconfiguration which setup some basic stuff. All the configuration is done via java config. I have a bunch of Controllers, static files residing in `classpath:/static/**` and templates in `classpath:/templates`. The Spring Boot autoconfiguration takes care of serving annotated controllers, thymeleaf templates and static files.

In the case of templates, I'm serving a bunch of them by using a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` overriding `addViewControllers` for direct URL to View mapping, for example, mapping URL `/index` to view `index.html` gets done by `registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index")`.

What I need is to establish a hierarchy of URL to Resource resolution with fallback, for example, if I type the URL `/x/y/z` Spring should check:

1. For a handler in a controller function `x/y/z`
2. For a bean handling `x/y/z`
3. For a thymeleaf template residing in `x/y/z`
4. For a static resource `x/y/z`
5. ELSE RETURN NOT_FOUND 404

SOLUTION #1. User M. Deinum suggested setup a `UrlFilenameViewController` as a default handler either in `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` or `BeanNameHandlerMapping`.

CAVEAT. That redirects works by mapping ALL requests to `UrlFilenameViewController`, the view gets resolved correctly but static resources, controller URL and everything else gets treated as view and thymeleaf view resolver complains by throwing a 500 error because the template was not found, so there's no graceful fallback.

SOLUTION #2. Use a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` add a mapping `"**/*.html"` and redirect such request to a `UrlFilenameViewController`.

CAVEAT. That gets Controllers, static resources and templates correctly resolved because request get isolated by the `*.html` mapping BUT if I type a `/x/y/foo-bar-view.html` again thymeleaf view resolver complains for a non existent template, so again no graceful fallback.

The solution should ideally throw at the end a 404 error after checking all the specified URL to Resource mappings.

Comment: You still need a controller, register the [`UrlFilenameViewController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/UrlFilenameViewController.html) and add it as the default handler to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. This will lead all non mapped requests to this controller which turns it into a view name.

Comment: Yeah is working! Now a side effect, if the template doesn't exists it throws a 500 error, at this point I want to throw a 404 to finish the thing, any insights @M.Deinum?

Comment: No, is overriding the complete thing. Now I cant get to my static resources, every URL is being treated as a template and throwing 500 error.

Comment: Well that is the drawback. Post some configuration (ordering of `HandlerMapping`s is relevant here). Instead of adding it to the `RequestMappingHandlerMappnig` create a new instance of a `HandlerMapping`  (for instance the `BeanNameHandlerMapping` order it as the last one to be consulted and add the controller as the default to that one). That way the other `HandlerMapping`s can do their thing first if all fail this is the fallback.

Comment: Is not working regardless of the HandlerMapping type or order, if I set the DefaultHandler the same behavior is shown.

Comment: Then you have something wrong in your setup.

Comment: I've checked and rechecked and tried all possible combinations to no avail. I'm thinking in implementing my own `HandlerMapping` because I can't find any example anywhere with this requirement.

Comment: We are using a similar setup in production without problems. The default handler should be on the last handler mapping. Please add your configuration to the post.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot with `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-security` enabled and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. Spring auto configuration setup `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` automatically I don't modify Boot autoconfiguration except to add `registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")` via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. If I `setDefaultHandler` to ANY of the 3 Handlers I get an error from ThymeLeaf template complaining is unable to find such template.

Comment: The best I can get is to use `UrlFilenameViewController` with a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` that maps **/*.html not an elegant solution. Also it throws `Error resolving template` if the URL doesn't have a corresponding Template.

Comment: It's possible that Thymeleaf is not handling properly the template-not-found case?

Comment: If there isn't a view there is nothing going to be rendered. If for the url `/foo/bar` there is no `foo/bar.html` you will get an exception. The views have to be there. Also you didn't mention Spring Boot nor Thymeleaf in your initial question!. What is it you want to happen, because I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: Could you expand the question (maybe with some configuration) and clarify a bit more on what you want? What is it that you want if no explicit mapping is found, should it create a view name or should always go to the same page?

Comment: OK I have added clarification and tested solutions.

Comment: Even though you want all those things to be checked based on the URL the first point of contact would be the mappings setup in the controller.  The solution 2 can be extended to work if you can you show your DispatcherServlet Initialization code?

Comment: I use Spring Boot auto configuration, so it does all for me.